# How to implement smooth scroll in a nuxt3 application

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, smooth-scrolling

I'm a rookie in nuxt3 and i can't figure out how to implement smooth scroll. I have added a `route.options.ts` file in ~/app/ and tested it out, but no success.

This is my `route.options.ts` file:

```js
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema';

// https://router.vuejs.org/api/#routeroptions
export default <RouterConfig>{
    scrollBehavior(to) {
        return { el: to.hash };
    },
};
```

And this is how I set the anchor links:

```html
<NuxtLink :to="{path: '', hash: '#testimonials'}">Let's go!</NuxtLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added

```css
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

to html in css and now it works.

Comment: This is somehow not working for me. In inspect element, I have the css rule in html but no luck.